# go-ethereum error 87 y 66 ejecutando Run --Race

Tags: go

Estoy teniendo un problema en GO al querer verificar la ejecucion con go run --race main.go

> ==15572==ERROR: ThreadSanitizer failed to allocate 0x000000699000 (6918144) bytes at 0x200dd2876c000 (error code: 87)
> exit status 66

Esto me esta pasando al usar tanto go-ethereum como hd-wallet cuando no importo ningun de esas librerias el error no sucede. Como soy nuevo en GO no la tengo tan clara a que se debe y no encuentre mucha información. Les dejo el codigo ejemplo de la propia libreria. Sabe a que puede deberse?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)

func main() {

    // Create an account
    key, err := crypto.GenerateKey()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Get the address
    address := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(key.PublicKey).Hex()
    // 0x8ee3333cDE801ceE9471ADf23370c48b011f82a6

    // Get the private key
    privateKey := hex.EncodeToString(key.D.Bytes())
    // 05b14254a1d0c77a49eae3bdf080f926a2df17d8e2ebdf7af941ea001481e57f
    fmt.Println("Address: ", address)
    fmt.Println("Private key: ", privateKey)
}
```